# How to enable intel iRIS Xe GPU for Deep Learning?

Tags: deep-learning, gpu, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, intel

When I train my data using google colab and when I switch my runtime to GPU. My colab only utilizes CPU but not GPU. How to enable using an Intel GPU of a Windows 10 system?

Answer (score 1):

To enable your notebook to use GPU runtime, select the Runtime > 'Change runtime type' menu, and then select GPU from the Hardware Accelerator drop-down.

Then you can ensure by running the following code in one of your notebook cell:

```
gpu_info = !nvidia-smi
gpu_info = '\n'.join(gpu_info)
if gpu_info.find('failed') >= 0:
  print('Select the Runtime > "Change runtime type" menu to enable a GPU accelerator, ')
  print('and then re-execute this cell.')
else:
  print(gpu_info)
```